# Access - colocar dados de uma tabela na horizontal

Tags: sql, microsoft-access

Olá!

Eu já pesquisei em diversos fórum, mas não consegui achar uma solução satisfatória. Eu tenho a seguinte tabela:

```
ID  COD VLR_REEMB   N_FICHA DT_RECEBIMENTO  
1   1   4.022,06    965     24/09/2010  
2   3   6.600,00    746     17/09/2013  
3   4   6.600,00    746     17/09/2013  
4   5   6.600,00    746     17/09/2013  
5   6   6.600,00    746     17/09/2013  
6   6   6.600,00    749     20/09/2013  
7   6   6.600,00    750     17/10/2013  
8   9   6.600,00    746     17/09/2013  
9   1   6.600,00    746     17/09/2013
```

O ID é único, as o cod pode se repetir. Por isso, gostaria de gerar uma consulta que me mostrasse a informação da seguinte forma:

```
COD    VLR1    FICHA1    DT1      VLR2    FICHA2    DT2    VLR3    FICHA3    DT3
1    4.022,06   965    24/09/2010
6    6.600,00   746    17/09/2016 6.600,00 749  20/09/2013 6.600,00 750 17/10/2013
```

Alguém com alguma sugestão sobre eu como posso fazer isso no Access?

---

Olá!

Agradeço pelo retorno, mas creio que o post indicado não sirva pra mim. Eu cheguei a ver uma solução parecida, mas pelo que entendi, ao utilizar o pivot table eu não posso indicar mais de uma coluna, que é exatamente o que preciso.

Segue o exemplo do que eu consegui fazer:

`TRANSFORM FIRST([N_FICHA]) AS FirstOfName
SELECT COD
FROM
    (
        SELECT t1.COD, t1.N_FICHA,'FICHA' & Format(COUNT(*),"00") AS NewName
        FROM
            TABELA1 AS t1
            INNER JOIN
            TABELA1  AS t2
                ON t1.COD = t2.COD
                    AND t1.N_FICHA >= t2.N_FICHA
        GROUP BY t1.COD, t1.N_FICHA
    )
GROUP BY COD
PIVOT NewName`

Isso me deu o seguinte resultado:

`COD    FICHA01 FICHA02 FICHA03
1   746 965 
3   746

4   746

5   746

6   746 749 750
9   746`

É exatamente isso que eu preciso, só que com as colunas adicionais ao lado de cada ficha. Alguma sugestão?

Comment: Por favor, veja se este post pode te ajudar: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16691853/transform-and-pivot-in-access-2013-sql](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16691853/transform-and-pivot-in-access-2013-sql)

Comment: Não serviu, conforme descrito no meu comentário anterior. Agradeço outras sugestões.